# why can't I pass jquery objects as arguments in functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a jQuery selected object into a function, and the function will do a `.html()` on it.

Html:

```
<div id="box">this is a box</div>
```

Js:

```
var fillBox = function(box, text) {
  box.html(text);
}

(function() {
  var box = $("#box");
  fillBox(box, "new text");
});
```

The box stays as `"this is a box"` and never gets updated, even tho the function is called. I even tried `$(box).html(text)` inside the function, but that doesn't fix it. Is this do-able?

http://jsbin.com/iqixoj/5/edit

Comment: Because the code runs before the element is rendered on the page!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot a `$`.

```
$(function() {
  var box = $("#box");
  fillBox(box, "new text");
});
```